# Express server don't start when I use "mongoose.connect'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm doing an App with React, Express and MongoDB,

Everything is OK when I start the Express server with this line :

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on ${port}`));
```

But when I try to start the server with this :

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.USER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB}`,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then(() =>
    console.log(
      `Server running on ${port} and connection to MongoDB database is OK !`
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I can't access to localhost:5000 (server port) and I have no error messages !

The env variables are OK, I logged them..

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting to MongoDB but not actually starting the server (which are two separate things):

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.USER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB}`,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then(() =>
    console.log(`Connection to MongoDB database is OK !`)
    // Start the server here
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on ${port}`));
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```